# Escape rubberband zoom in qtchartview

Tags: c++, qt5

I'm working with Qt 5.7.0 and I'm using a qchartview to display a qchart object. The view is set up so that the user can zoom on the chart by drawing a rectangluar box. That's simple enough to code:

```
QChart *myChart = new QChart;
QChartView *myView = new QChartView;
myView->setRubberBand(QChartView::RectangleRubberBand);
myView->setChart(myChart);
```

And everything works well. But what I would like to do is have a way to escape the zoom. If the user left clicks on the chart and starts drawing the box, they should be able to press a button or right click or something so that the zoom does not happen. I apologize if this is in the documentation somewhere but I did not see it.

Comment: What do you mean with _"a way to escape the zoom"_? You want a way to **restore** the default zoom level or something different?

Comment: not a way to restore a zoom level. if you hold down the left mouse button and drag the mouse, you will start drawing the rectangular box. no zooming will actually take place until you release the left mouse button. but before you release the button, you may decide that you actually don't want to zoom.

i'm not sure if anyone is familiar with gnuplot, but what you can do with that plotter is press the escape key and the zooming will not happen.

hopefully i made the problem clearer.